# Rails 5.1: polymorphic association create/update record with additional data saved in Join table

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), which looks something like this:

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permitable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  enum status: {creator: 1, editor: 2}
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permissions, class_name: 'Permission'
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permissions, class_name: 'Permission', as: :permitable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, class_name: 'User', through: :permissions
end
```

I need to do save/update multiple `users` for `books` and for each saved `user` set `permission.status`.

Lets say for `book=Book.first` I need to add:

1) `user=User.find(2)` with `permission.creator`

2) `user=User.find(1)` with `permission.editor`

In ideal world I would need to do it in one query.
How do I do this, please? Thank you!

**Update**

At the moment I can do:

```
def create
  Book.create(book_params)
end

private

def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:name, {user_ids[]})
end
```

This would create record in `Book` and add record in `Permission`, but would not set `status` there.

Probably not the best example with `Permission` model - it's for example purposes and maybe is confusing. Should I change that to something else?

**Update 2**

I've added `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `Book` model:

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permitable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  belongs_to :user

  enum status: {creator: 1, editor: 2}
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permissions, class_name: 'Permission'
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permissions, class_name: 'Permission', as: :permitable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :permissions
  has_many :users, class_name: 'User', through: :permissions
end
```

then in my controller:

```
def create
  Book.create(:name, permissions_attributes: [{user_id: "1", status: :creator},
                                              {user_id: "2", status: :owner}])
end

private

def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:name, {permissions_attributes[:user_id, :status]})
end
```

How do I create some loop to do `create` dynamically, please?

Comment: What has `book=Book.first` got to do with updating `user=User.find(2)`?? Can you show a complete, working example of the current implementation?

Comment: Also, `Item` is a very confusing model name IMO. What is it supposed to represent?

Comment: @TomLord Please, see update above. At the moment I can do single record for `current_user` however I need to do this for multiple selected users from list.

Comment: @TomLord I tweaked my code a bit, so I can save multiple `user_ids` at the moment. Now I have to somehow add those statuses fore each `User`.

Comment: To set the item status, you could just define a default value on the model? I'm still unclear what logic you're actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: @TomLord I changed the whole question above so it looks close to what I have in real life. Basically I need to give specific record level access to specific users. I'm using [Strongbolt gem](https://github.com/605data/strongbolt) for authorization, however I need to implement record level authorization for specific functionality.

Comment: My possible answer and question remain unchanged... I don't see how renaming `item`-->`permission` changes things, or the relevance of `strongbolt`. if you need newly created `Book`s to belong to a `Permission`  with `status = :creator`, then why not make this a default value? And I don't understand what instances of `Permission` will need their statuses set to `editor`

Comment: @TomLord I want to give access to particular `Book` record to two users - one will be `creator` and another will be `editor`. How do I create such `Book` record with particular `permissions` for those two users, please? I've set default value in my PostgreSQL for `status`, that is not an issue.

Comment: OHHHH... OK, I understand now. You've overcomplicated the data model... Hang on, I'll answer below.

Comment: @TomLord Ok, thank you. I'm using Polymorphic association, because I have few models like `Book`.

Answer (score 0):

If each `book` can only have **one** creator and **one** editor, you could just do this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Maybe you'd like to define e.g. `created_books` and `edited_books`?
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :editor, class_name: 'User'
end
```

If the book can have **one** creator and **many** editors, you could instead do this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Maybe you'd like to define e.g. `created_books` and `edited_books`?
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :editors, through: :book_editors
end

class BookEditor
  belongs_to :editor, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :book
end
```

---

When you create a book, pass in he `creator_id` and the `editor_id`/`editor_ids` (if it's a `has_many` relationship):

```
def create
  Book.create(book_params)
end

private

def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:name, :creator_id, editor_ids:[])
end
```

I don't see the need for polymorphism here.

Comment: I see your idea, however I need this to work on few models so I believe polymorphic approach would be OK. Could you, please, take a look on my Update 2 above? I think I'm almost there since I added `accept_nested_attributes_for`. I think if I added some loop for creating multiple records, that would work. Could you help there, please?

Comment: What you're doing isn't even polymorphism; it's more like single table inheritance - but with only one class, and a `status` column instead of the standard `type`. I really don't see any value in the design; it just adds complication and damages performance.

Comment: But yes, you *could* do it this way with two `Permission.create!` calls.

Comment: Ok, I see. How particular design damages performance? I may think of different design probably.

Comment: Performance is damaged by the (1) the additional DB queries needed to create a book, and (2) the additional/more complex DB queries to find out e.g. "the book's creator". Currently, you'd need to "find the user, through permissions, where `permissions.status = :created`"; as opposed to just finding a user by id!

Comment: If you have **lots** of status types, then there may be some virtue to your approach; but if there's only `creator` and `editor(s)` then just use two foreign keys...

Comment: Thank you, for clearing out. Most probably I will have 3 statuses, however I will need to give permissions to few other Models as well. Can I solve that with your suggested approach, please?